# How can I make two features enabled lead to a conflict in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have two features: `feature_1` and `feature_2`:

```
[features]
default = ["feature_1"]
feature_1 = []
feature_2 = []
```

I want to let the user choose only one of them at a time because choosing both at the same time will lead to a duplicating of some important code and by some other reasons. How can I do that?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/2980

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fundamentally, you can't.  Cargo features are additive, and features can be enabled by any crate in the dependency tree.  There's an implicit assumption on the part of Cargo that it is *always* valid to enable additional features.

What's more, features aren't simply requests, they are *demands*.  If one crate demands `feature_1`, and another crate demands `feature_2`, you've got two crates that cannot possibly work together.  Cargo (and Rust itself) go to some lengths to try and make such situations difficult to create.

The best solution is to change how your crate is written such that both features can be enabled simultaneously.  If that's really impossible, the best you can do is prevent compilation from succeeding.  This can be done either with a build script for your crate that detects incompatible features and fails, or by placing non-compiling code in your crate that is only enabled when incompatible features are enabled.

Comment: Making you crate not compile when both features accessed will soon be supported by an additional macro: compile_fail! https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/42620

Comment: Why can't you just have each feature flag conditionally compile a type named `YouMayOnlyUseOneOfFeatureAOrFeatureB`? If both features are enabled, the code will fail to compile.

Comment: @Shepmaster: "... or by placing non-compiling code in your crate that is only enabled when incompatible features are enabled."

Comment: @DK. that's like... all the way at the end of the answer. :-P I guess I read *Fundamentally, you can't* and then was like "sure I can". Maybe the wording of that first bit could be improved?

Comment: @Shepmaster: The problem is that you can't do it in a way that Cargo is aware of, you can only do it as a side-effect of deliberately breaking compilation.  Fundamentally, you can't just take gold out of the Federal Reserve Bank of New York without permission... I mean, *unless* you derail a subway train and bring in digging equipment, but I don't think that counts toward being able to say "yes, you can".

Comment: Hmm. I guess I don't read the implied "a way that Cargo is aware of" in the OP's question.

Answer (score 9):

For what it's worth, I opted to use this approach:

```
#[cfg(all(feature = "feature_1", feature = "feature_2"))]
compile_error!("Feature 1 and 2 are mutually exclusive and cannot be enabled together");
```

I hope it'll help others looking for a solution to the same problem.